# Get the index of a control : Controls.IndexOf returns -1

Tags: c#, .net

In the following block of code, I try to insert a control right before the current control iterated in the foreach. In order to do it, I give my new control the index of the current iterated control in order to push it forward when the control takes its place.

My problem is `Controls.IndexOf` returns -1, therefore the control is added at the end of the page.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls.OfType<System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder>().ToList())
{
    foreach (Control cc in c.Controls.OfType<System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl>().ToList())
    {
        if (cc is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl iframe = cc as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl;
            if (iframe.Attributes["src"].Contains("slideshare"))
            {
                Response.Write("INDEX:"+this.Controls.IndexOf(cc)); // returns -1 
                iframe.Attributes["src"] = "/img/content/cookielaw_slideshare.jpg";

                Literal lit=new Literal();
                lit.Text = @"<div class='cookieLaw_slideshare'><a id='cookieLaw_slideshare' href='#'><img src='/img/content/cookielaw_slideshare.jpg'/></a></div>";
                Page.Controls.AddAt(this.Controls.IndexOf(cc),lit);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Don´t you want this `this.Controls.IndexOf(c)`? cause `cc` is not part of the controls collection of `this`

Comment: What about if you change this:`Response.Write("INDEX:"+this.Controls.IndexOf(cc));`into this: `Response.Write("INDEX:"+c.Controls.IndexOf(iframe));`

Comment: Yes , writting iframe instead works but still get the exception : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index at the "addat" lne

Comment: Try this: `Page.Controls.AddAt(c.Controls.IndexOf(iframe),lit);`

Comment: Sorry,i think it should be `c.Controls.AddAt(c.Controls.IndexOf(iframe),lit);`

Comment: Just tried and i get the following exception now : 
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). 


:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for controls inside the form (c) and then controls inside that control (cc). So cc is c.controls, no this.controls.

Change:

```
Response.Write("INDEX:"+this.Controls.IndexOf(cc));
```

With:

```
Response.Write("INDEX:"+c.Controls.IndexOf(cc));
```

Comment: Thank you for warning about that ! Unfortunately, it does not solve my problem , indexOf still returns -1 ... :/

Comment: well actually , i get the following exception : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

Comment: If you debbug, does cc appear in c.Controls? Maybe an IndexOf(Iframe)?

Comment: IndexOf(iframe) returns 15 yes. 
But still getting the exception written above at the "addat" line...

Comment: I still don't get why indexOf(cc) is different from indexOf(iframe)

Comment: I'm not a big expert in `Web.UI` but maybe IndexOf needs a typed object and not just a generic one...

Comment: indexOf(cc) works too, sorry. but now i have a new exception : "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)." , we tried to update the addat line to c.Controls.AddAt(c.Controls.IndexOf(iframe),lit);

Comment: I have no idea about code blocks, but usually you can't modify a collection within a for each of that collection. How many Literal do you want to add to each c? One or more?

Comment: Yes , i need to add just one

Comment: Try to add it outside the second for each, if the problem is that you can modify c.controls it should solve it.

Comment: Just found my mistake.

I had just one Placeholder for the whole page. I tried to add one in Head and one in body and it suddenly works

Answer (score 0):

If you insert control inside foreach loop you're messing with original collection... so be careful with that.

**If the control is not found in the collection**, the IndexOf method return value is -1.